# Reload $(document).ready(function() After ajax page is reloaded

Tags: jquery

i have a common js file 
after I reload html page in ajax request , I cant access the functions in this file , the common JS functions between  **$(document).ready(function()** 
How can Access them and fire the functions in common file 
**Example** :

COMMON JS :

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 

 $(".agree_btn").click(function(){
        alert(123);             
    });

});
```

the Function in the **phtml** page

```
$('.loadMoreAnswers').live('click', function(event) {

          var location_id = $(this).attr('location_id');
          var counter= $(this).attr('counter');
                $('#loadingAnswer').show();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/daleel/loadmore',
            data: 'location_id='+location_id+'&part='+'answers'+'&answerCounter='+counter,  //with the page number as a parameter
            success: function(msg){

                if(msg.length!=0)    //if no errors
                { $(this).parent().load("view")
                    $('#loadingAnswer').remove();
                    counter+=5;
                    $('#profile-page-answer').append(msg); 

                } 
                else $("#loadingAnswer").remove();

            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });

              });
```

its render the HTML like This :

```
<a agreed="no" agreed-content-id="63066" class="agree_btn" id="agree-a63066">
Agree
    </a>
```

But when i click on this Link 
it doesnt run the function in the Common JS file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rebind the click event handler in the ajax success

```
success: function(msg){
 //your code
 $(".agree_btn").bind('click');
}
```

or you can use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for jQuery versions lower than 1.7 like

```
$(document).delegate(".agree_btn",'click',function(e){
 //your code
});
```

or of you are using jQuery version 1.7+ use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
$(document).on("click",".agree_btn",function(e){
 //your code
});
```

do not use `.live` its deprecated [*docs*](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: where to put the .success(fucntion()){ }

Comment: @KJA sry for the confusion the success handler is already added in your ajax call i have edited the answer

Comment: Its doesn't bind with the function in common js . or maybe i didnt understand it good

Comment: Does this Bind it with the function in the common js ?

Comment: this will re bind all the elements with class=agree_btn to the click event handler irrespective of where you define the event handler, i would personally go with the delegate solution

Comment: what argument should I use for bind() to rebind actions assigned to the link like "ajax:success", "ajax:error"

Answer (score 0):

Use `live()` inside common js file. for eg

```
$('selector').click(function(){
//function body
})
```

instead of this use

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){
//function body
})
```

Comment: Starting from scratch you might want to use .on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) ) prior to .live() because this method is deprecated in version 1.7 and will not be supported in future versions of jquery http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score -1):

Embedd document.ready function after the ajax complete. It will re-register the script on the page after ajax call.

Eg:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'deleteEntry',
            data: {'ids': JSON.stringify(getList)},
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('error');
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                //add your script in body here
            }
        });
```